# Android torrent client with remote access via browser and torrent time scheduler

Tags: android, web-apps, bittorrent

I'm looking for an advanced torrent client for Android with the following features:

- remote access via browser (I want to control my android box from my PC browser)
- torrent time scheduler (I want to specify in which hours the torrent must be downloaded)

I've searched a lot, but all the torrent clients for Android are identical and offer the same basic features.

Anyone can suggest me a torrent client with these features or a workaround to obtain them with any torrent client?

Comment: You want to run the torrent client *in* android? What sort of device would this be? What sort of connection would you use? The reason that these clients are limited are probably cause downloading torrents on a mobile system are likely to be massively expensive.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Hello there! My device is HCL ME U1. I use wifi which is unlimited. I have Android 4.3.0 and what do you mean by expensive? Ask me if more information is needed

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't tried it on an Android system but there seems to be a [`vuze` for Android](https://www.vuze.com/products/vuze-android/) that features:

> - Simple torrent search and discovery
> - Manage torrent downloads
> - Control torrent download/upload speed
> - Straightforward interface
> - Works for Android phones and tablets
> - Wi-Fi only setting
> - Task completion alerts
> - Auto-start on device reboot
> - Ad-free experience

I know that the Linux version of *vuze* offers both a [plugin](http://plugins.vuze.com/plugin_details.php?plugin=azhtmlwebui) that gives an http interface and vuze themselves offer something called ["Vuze Remote"](http://remote.vuze.com/) that allows you to connect and control your `vuze` instance over the internet. There is also a plugin called ["Vuze Scheduler"](http://plugins.vuze.com/plugin_details.php?plugin=SpeedScheduler) which should do what you want. Basically, there is a plugin for most anything you can imagine.

I stress that I have not used this on Android but I see no reason why it shouldn't work, especially since it works fine on Linux.